# Texture Paint draws somewhere else than where I want

Tags: modeling, texture-painting, uv-image-editor

I have a huge problem using Texture Paint.

When i try to color the character this happens:

[image]

I try to shade my characters but then it just draws somewhere else that is not even close to the damn thing. I did try to change the "bleed" settings but it still kept happening.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off Symmetry in the toolbar. This option is used when you're texturing stuff like faces or anything that is symmetrical, but if you're going for ones that aren't symmetrical then just turn off symmetry.

Just scroll down to the very bottom and you'll see it there.  [image]

Comment: My computer doesnt let me open Imgur links for some reason, any other way you can send it to me?

Comment: @Crowny oof, i cant think of any other way

Comment: Awh, Well, can you at least tell me which side the bar is in? I'll figure the rest out myself. Somehow. Hopefully.

Comment: @Crowny just scroll down the toolbar and you'll see symmetry xd

Comment: Alright i saw what you meant, but it was actually turned off. None of it were active. That wasnt really my problem but its fine, i'll try to find it myself. Thanks.

Comment: @Crowny oh, well can you explain a bit more? i didn't really understand and thought you were trying to just shade one place. don't mind me

Comment: It's fine dont worry lol i suck at talking. So, here is another gif of the problem https://i.gyazo.com/d479674bc0d2180a76ad8aec08547ab6.gif   See how when i draw there are white lines and also weird triangles it creates around it? Those are my problem. It always happens. Whenever i try to shade, color. It just does that.

Comment: @Crowny hmm... i'm kind of confused. cuz on the first gif i see that once you start drawing there's these weird lines that are on the top of your model, but on the second gif it just looks like unaffected parts to me. :/

Comment: Look at the nose part (the middle of the model) while im drawing on the second gif, maybe that's what you're looking for.

Comment: @Crowny those triangles on the nose?

Comment: Yeah, as i draw they also kept happening on other models as well.

Comment: @Crowny well that sucks. the only thing i can think of is the unwrapping of the model, but then aside from that i can't think of anything else. have you checked the UV maps and the unwrapping?